# Al usar dos bucles WHILE en C solo me ejecuta el primero

Tags: c, while

Si comento uno de los dos cualquiera que sea, funciona el otro, pero los dos a la vez no funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char fichero1;
char linea[1024];
int cuenta;
char letra;
char c;
main()
{
printf("Itroduce el nombre de un fichero en esta carpeta(ejemplo:origen.txt): \n");
scanf("%s", &fichero1);
printf("\n");

FILE *archivo, *archivo2;

archivo=fopen(&fichero1,"r");
archivo2=fopen("destino.txt","w");

if (archivo==NULL)

{printf("Imposible abrir fichero");}

else
{
    cuenta = 0;
    printf("Fichero abierto:\n");
    while ((letra = getc(archivo)) != EOF) {
        if(letra == '\n') {
        printf(" ");
        printf("(%d)\n", cuenta);
        cuenta = 0;

        } else {
        cuenta++;
        printf("%c", letra);
        }

    }
while (!feof(archivo))
    {
        fscanf(archivo,"%c",&c);
        if (c==' ' || c=='\t')
        {fprintf(archivo2,"");
         while (c==' ' || c=='\t')
         fscanf(archivo,"%c",&c);}
        fprintf(archivo2,"%c",c);
    }

fclose(archivo);
fclose(archivo2);
 printf("\n Texto copiado sin espacios en destino.txt \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en el primer while lees todo el archivo, y el puntero se queda en el final, la solucion es usar rewind() asi:

```
    while ((letra = getc(archivo)) != EOF) {
        if(letra == '\n') {
        printf(" ");
        printf("(%d)\n", cuenta);
        cuenta = 0;

        } else {
        cuenta++;
        printf("%c", letra);
        }

    }
rewind(archivo);
while (!feof(archivo))
    {
        fscanf(archivo,"%c",&c);
        if (c==' ' || c=='\t')
        {fprintf(archivo2,"");
         while (c==' ' || c=='\t')
         fscanf(archivo,"%c",&c);}
        fprintf(archivo2,"%c",c);
    }
```

Comment: te quiero amig@

Comment: Si te funciono, marca la respuesta como correcta

Comment: En cuanto me deje hacerlo